# DESeqDataSetFromTximport invalid rownames length

Tags: deseq2

I am trying to use `DESeqDataSetFromTximport` function from `DESeq2` package to construct `dds` object:

```
dds <- DESeqDataSetFromTximport(txi, sampleTable, ~Group)
```

And somehow it is giving me the following error:

> Error in `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("ENSMUSG00000000001", "ENSMUSG00000000003",  : 
>     invalid rownames length

I used the same code for other datasets but for the current one it is somehow not working. My `sampleTable` looks like this:

```
       ID      Group
1    de_1 denervated
2    de_2 denervated
3    de_3 denervated
4    de_4 denervated
5   den_5       sham
6    ho_1        IgG
7    ho_2        IgG
8    ho_3        IgG
9    sh_1       sham
10   sh_2       sham
11   sh_3       sham
12   sh_4       sham
13   sh_5       sham
14 VLA_10  anti-VLA4
15 VLA_12  anti-VLA4
16  VLA_7  anti-VLA4
```

`txi` was formed in the following way:

```
k = keys(txdb, keytype = "GENEID")
df = AnnotationDbi::select(txdb, keys = k, keytype = "GENEID", columns = "TXNAME")
tx2gene = df[, 2:1]  # tx ID, then gene ID
txi <- tximport(names, type = "salmon", tx2gene = tx2gene)
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: That error message suggests that something is very wrong with `txi` can you post some of its contents and say how you created it?

Comment: The code for `txi` creation is at the very bottom of the last code piece. I created it from the `names` array that is pointing to the relevant `.sf` files. The thing is that everything was working fine and then just suddenly stopped. I suppose some `install.packages()` run just messed up all of the installation. Currently I am having a lot of trouble with reinstalling everything from scratch. I do not know though, whether it will actually fix anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got exactly the same problem not long ago (see my [other](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/5531/how-should-i-address-batch-effects-in-my-experiment) question what I tried to do). We used the same function!

My code ran fine on my HPC but the same code/data failed on my laptop. I later found out I had to upgrade my R to the latest version (3.5.1) and upgrade all my bioconductor packages to the latest. My HPC was on a recent bioconductor docker, so there was no problem.

Please make sure everything in your environment latest (R, R packages, Bioconductor).

Comment: Actually I tried updating packages with `update.packages()` function, but it did not help. I already have the latest `R` version `3.5.1`. Then, I reinstalled `tximport`, `DESeq2` and no success either

Comment: I agree, that was the issue. I was able to solve it though only by reinstalling everything through `bioconda` in a way described in the question I asked later on: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/5538/install-deseq2-through-anaconda .    It is interesting that such an error `invalid rownames length` comes up precisely when packages installation was messed up and it is very misleading. I just got it the second time on a different computer.

Answer (score 2):

The same error occurred to me with `DESeq2_1.22.2` using `R 3.5.0`.
By trial and error, I managed to solve the issue when I updated `SummarizedExperiment` from `1.10.1` to `1.12.0`.