# Install DESeq2 through anaconda

Tags: deseq2

I tried running `conda install -c bioconda bioconductor-deseq2` in a `conda` environment, but when I run `R` console and try to import `DESeq2` I am getting the error message:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘GenomeInfoDb’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
>    there is no package called ‘GenomeInfoDbData’
>   Error: package ‘GenomeInfoDb’ could not be loaded

When I try installing `GenomeInfoDbData` and `GenomeInfoDb` using `conda`, it says that the packages were already installed. If I run `install.packages(GenomeInfoDb)` from `R` console, it is telling me that the package is not available for `R` version `3.5.1`.

I want to import `DESeq2` in `Rstudio` though and it is giving me a different error when I try importing `DESeq2`:

> Error in library("DESeq2") : there is no package called ‘DESeq2’

I do not get why `Rstudio` does not see that I alrerady installed `DESeq2` with `conda`. If I try running `biocLite("DESeq2")` from `Rstudio` I get the following error:

> Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
>     unable to load shared object '/Users/nikitavlasenko/miniconda3/envs/renv/lib/R/library/cluster/libs/cluster.so':
>     dlopen(/Users/nikitavlasenko/miniconda3/envs/renv/lib/R/library/cluster/libs/cluster.so, 6): Symbol not found: _libintl_dgettext
>     Referenced from: /Users/nikitavlasenko/miniconda3/envs/renv/lib/R/library/cluster/libs/cluster.so
>     Expected in: /Users/nikitavlasenko/miniconda3/envs/renv/lib/R/lib/libR.dylib
>    in /Users/nikitavlasenko/miniconda3/envs/renv/lib/R/library/cluster/libs/cluster.so
>   ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘Hmisc’
>   * removing ‘/Users/nikitavlasenko/miniconda3/envs/renv/lib/R/library/Hmisc’
>   ERROR: dependency ‘Hmisc’ is not available for package ‘DESeq2’
>   * removing ‘/Users/nikitavlasenko/miniconda3/envs/renv/lib/R/library/DESeq2’

So, supposedly the issue is with `Hmisc`. I installed the package successfully with `conda`, but `Rstudio` is apparently does not know about it. Running `install.packages("Hmisc")` gives the first part of the error with missing `cluster.so` library.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the R you're running from the command line is installed through Anaconda as well? What is the output of `which R`?  
As for RStudio, that's weird... Seems like it's aware of your Conda installation, although could be some conda env tomfoolery.

Comment: Please remember to confirm an answer once you've received one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ultimately my colleague helped me to solve the issue by following the steps:

1. Created environment: `conda create --name myenv`
2. Activated it: `source activate myenv`
3. Edited `.condarc` to set the priority of the channels to be the following (top to bottom): `conda-forge`, `bioconda`, `r`, `default`
4. Checked that the channels are set in the correct order: `conda config --get channels`
5. `conda install r=3.5.1`
6. `conda install r-essentials`
7. `conda install rstudio`
8. Installation of all of the `bioconductor` packages through `bioconda` and never install anything from inside `R` or `Rstudio` (I guess that is how it was broken)

Then launching `rstudio` from within the environment. Maybe it is not a kind of quick fix and it could have been solved easier, but I was not able to.

Comment: The issue here was likely that you used two different package managers (conda and R), each setting and managing their own paths. I would argue that the conclusion to *never install anything from inside R or Rstudio* is misleading, as the latter has a perfectly fine package manager - as long as you don't mix your installations.

Comment: Yeah, just need to select one way of doing it and never use the other. Idk, but the issue came up from using installations from within R/Rstudio, and maybe it will never happen if we use just `conda`, hard to say.

Comment: Much like the issues raised in [this blog post from Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/developer-blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/), mixing package managers can cause some headaches. If you can, try and stick to one method, but, unfortunately, it seems like that's often not possible

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you might have an issue with which `R` Rstudio is running.
If you didn't install Rstudio through `conda`, Rstudio may be using its own version of `R` that is bundled with Rstudio, instead of the one you've installed via `conda`.

Assuming that your `conda` environment name is `renv`, try running this in the terminal:

```
$ conda activate renv
$ conda install r::rstudio -y

$ which rstudio
/Users/nikitavlasenko/miniconda3/envs/renv/bin/rstudio
# or something like this ^

# run Rstudio as a background shell process
rstudio &
```

This should open up the Rstudio interface, like normal, but using everything defined in your `renv` environment.

If you try loading the `DEseq2` library now, that might work.

Comment: My `R` is pointing to conda, but not to virtual environment of the conda. Rstudio is pointing to virtual environment. So, now I do not know how I can switch R to the one used by the virtual environment.

Comment: @NikitaVlasenko you should be able to point Rstudio to the `R` under `envs/something/bin/`.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, this is likely an issue with having multiple versions of R or RStudio installed.

I highly recommend that any R/RStudio version not installed inside conda be removed. This includes any installed libraries.

I've previously written a [blog post](https://jlboat.github.io/how-to-set-up-a-bioinformatics-environment.html) about this topic, and I can say from experience that installing R packages through conda can cause lots of headaches.

You'll have an easier time if you install R/RStudio via conda and then install R packages the traditional way, inside R/RStudio.

So, for example.

Bad: `conda install -c bioconda bioconductor-deseq2`

Good:

```
conda install rstudio
# Then, inside RStudio
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("DESeq2")
```